# How to reflect from an ellipse while solving a system of differential equations?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, coordinate-transformation, event-detection

While solving a system of differential equations to plot trajectories, we can use NDSolve and WhenEvent like shown [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/billiard-balls.html).

I am trying to solve this for a system of equations (Hamiltons Equations) for a free particle, so that the reflection is from a surface of ellipse (like elliptical pool table).

[image: H=\frac{pr(t)^2}{2 m}+\frac{pth(t)^2}{2 m r(t)^2}]

Where r and th are r and theta coordinates.

In the r, theta cordinates, the equation of ellipse reads as:

[image: fun2]

The initial conditions I have given (in the variable of time i.e. r(t), theta(t), etc) are r(t=0)= 2.29 (which is r(theta=Pi)), theta(t=0) = Pi, pr(t=0)=1, pth(t=0) = 0.
Where pr and pth are radial and angular momentum given by [Hamilton's Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Overview)

This is how I am implementing it, but the reflection is occurring from a circle and not an ellipse. Please help.

The code is:

```
b=1;
eps=0.9;
m=1;
R=b/(Sqrt[1-(eps*Cos[th])^2]);
H = pr[t]^2/(2*m) + pth[t]^2/(2*m*r[t]^2);
xxx = NDSolve[{r'[t] == D[H, pr[t]],th'[t] == D[H, pth[t]], pr'[t] == -D[H, r[t]], pth'[t] == -D[H, th[t]],r[0] == 2.29, th[0] == Pi, pr[0] == 1, pth[0] == 0,WhenEvent[r[t]^2 == (b/Sqrt[1 - (eps*Cos[th[t]])^2])^2, pr[t] -> -pr[t]]}, {r[t], th[t], pr[t], pth[t]},{t, 0,100}]
Show[PolarPlot[{xxx[[1]][[1]][[2]]}, {t, 0, 100}],PolarPlot[b/(Sqrt[1 - (eps*Cos[th])^2]), {th, 0, 2*Pi},PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

The output I get is a very pretty but wrong image:[image]

The trajectories must lie inside the ellipse (red), because the reflection condition given by WhenEvent defines the boundary of the circle.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess this would be simpler in Cartesian coordinates...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher May be, but the next extension of the problem which I wish to solve will be easier to be solved in Polar Coordinates. I wish to stick to this coordinate system!

Comment: Then you have to express the normal of the boundary ellipsoid and apply a reflection of the speed vector with respect to this normal in the `WhenEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem here is the use of `PolarPlot`. Once we use `PolarPlot`, the function takes the parameter 't' as the theta variable and hence generates faulty graph.

Here the interpolating functions generated are of $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$. We need to do a `ParametricPlot` of $r(t)cos(\theta(t))$ vs $r(t)sin(\theta(t))$ and it will give the correct graph.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{xxx[[1]][[1]][[2]]*Cos[xxx[[1]][[2]][[2]]], xxx[[1]][[1]][[2]]*Sin[xxx[[1]][[2]][[2]]]}, {t, 0, 100}], PolarPlot[b/Sqrt[1 - (eps*Cos[th])^2], {th, 0, 2*Pi}],PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `PolarPlot` specifically is looking to plot the radius as a function of $\theta$, not a parametric curve.

Comment: It looks like the angles of incidence do not equal the angles of reflection in your plot.  I suspect the Sin and Cos in your equation would work better for a circle than an ellipse.